# Group by all elements of a column, in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the dataframe:

```
elements1    |    elements2
   a                 dog
   b                 dog
   a                 cat
   x                 cat
   c                 cat
   m                 pig
   k                 pig
...
```

and I want to obtain a dataframe of the form:

```
elements1    |    elements2
   a, b              dog
   a, x, c           cat
   m, k              pig
...
```

where we essentially group by `elements2` and divide the corresponding `elements1` with a comma. All items in this dataframe are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use `groupby`, `apply` and a `lambda` where we join all the matching elements with a comma.

```
df1 = df.groupby('elements2')['elements1'].apply(lambda x : ','.join(x)).reset_index()


cols = ['elements1','elements2'] # sort cols by your desired input. 

print(df1[cols].sort_values('elements1'))
  elements1 elements2
1       a,b       dog
0     a,x,c       cat
2       m,k       pig
```